# Access SQL Filtering out records via junction table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that returns all scenarios that I have in a scenarios table

```
SELECT DISTINCT RiskScenarios.riskScenID, RiskScenarios.riskScenName
FROM RiskScenarios
```

I also have a query that returns the same fields as above, but this time uses a junction table and a list box on a form to return just the scenarios in which a specific risk applies

```
Select RiskScenarios.riskScenID, RiskScenarios.riskScenName
FROM RiskScenarios INNER JOIN TopRiskstoScenarios
ON RiskScenarios.riskScenID = TopRiskstoScenarios.riskScenID
WHERE TopRiskstoScenarios.topRiskID = [Forms]![ERMForm]![lTopRisks]
```

What I would like to do is return the records in the first query while omitting the records in the second, which I am attempting to do as

```
SELECT DISTINCT RiskScenarios.riskScenID, RiskScenarios.riskScenName
FROM RiskScenarios
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select RiskScenarios.riskScenID, RiskScenarios.riskScenName
FROM RiskScenarios INNER JOIN TopRiskstoScenarios
ON RiskScenarios.riskScenID = TopRiskstoScenarios.riskScenID
WHERE TopRiskstoScenarios.topRiskID = [Forms]![ERMForm]![lTopRisks])
```

However, this query returns no rows. I'm completely stumped and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RiskScenarios.riskScenID, RiskScenarios.riskScenName 
FROM RiskScenarios 
LEFT JOIN (Select TopRiskstoScenarios.riskScenID FROM TopRiskstoScenarios 
WHERE TopRiskstoScenarios.topRiskID = [Forms]![ERMForm]![lTopRisks]) AS TopRisk
ON RiskScenarios.riskScenID = TopRisk.riskScenID 
WHERE TopRisk.riskScenID IS NULL
```

The `LEFT JOIN` includes all rows from the 'left table' `RiskScenarios`, and *only those records* matching RiskScenarios.riskScenID from the 'right table' (the subquery tagged as `TopRisk`).

Where there is no matching `TopRisk.riskScenID`, this query returns `NULL`. The final `WHERE` clause removes the non-null matches, leaving only `RiskScenarios` with no match in `TopRisk`.

Comment: kismert, this is perfect! Thank you for also explaining why it works. This is a great help and I would buy you a beer if I could.